# Time Schedule Error

Tags: java, time, timer, scheduled-tasks

Please have a look at the following code

```
public class Test {

    public Test()
    {
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(new TimerTask(){
        public void run()
        {
            System.out.println("Updated");
        }
        }, System.currentTimeMillis(),1000);



    }

    public static void main(String[]args)
    {
        new Test();
    }


}
```

In here, you can see it is not printing anything! In other words, the time is not scheduled! Why is that? I want to schedule the task to happen in every second. Please help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are telling the `Timer` to wait (approximately) 1363531420 milliseconds before executing your `TimerTask`. This works out to ~42 years. You should be using [`Timer.schedule(yourTask, 0, 1000)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html#schedule%28java.util.TimerTask,%20long,%20long%29).

Answer (score 2):

Try to execute this code:

```
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class Test {

    public Test()
    {
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(new TimerTask(){
        public void run()
        {
            System.out.println("Updated");
        }
        }, 0,1000);



    }

    public static void main(String[]args)
    {
        new Test();
    }


}
```

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html), there are two methods:

```
schedule(TimerTask task, Date firstTime, long period) 
schedule(TimerTask task, long delay, long period)
```

You are passing in `(TimerTask, long, long)` and are therefore invoking the second one - i.e. schedule the task to run for the first time in `System.currentTimeMillis()` millis and every second thereafter. So your task will run for the first time at `Thu Jun 01 06:45:28 BST 2056`, to find that out:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {        
    System.out.println(new Date(2*System.currentTimeMillis()));
}
```

You need to invoke the method with zero:

```
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("Updated");
        }
    }, 0, 1000);
```

This means schedule the task to run for the first time in zero millis and every second thereafter.

Answer (score 0):

You have set the delay to the current time in millis (which would be a very long time :) ).  You probably intended this:

```
public class Test {

    public Test()
    {
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(new TimerTask(){
            public void run()
            {
                System.out.println("Updated");
            }
        }, new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()),1000); //<--- Notice a date is being constructed


    }

    public static void main(String[]args)
    {
        new Test();
    }

}
```

Where you set the firstTime to the current date.

Comment: While this would work, `new Date()` is shorthand for `new Date(System.currentTimeMillis())` and it would be better to invoke with `0` anyway.

Comment: Yes, new Date() is shorthand for new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()).  I was just being explicit to be clear.